# Can we Fetch data from Apache solr to our website using node.js?

Tags: node.js, solr

**I want to show the JSON object from apache solr in my node.js server but it keeps me showing the error as I am trying to show it in my node.js server. Is there any way so that I can show the json data which contains images as well in my server**

**please help!**

```
var SolrNode = require('solr-node');

// Create client
var client = new SolrNode({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '8983',
    core: 'new_core',
    protocol: 'http'
});
 
// Set logger level (can be set to DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL or OFF)
require('log4js').getLogger('solr-node').level = 'DEBUG';


var strQuery = client.query().q('type2:veg');

 var data;
client.search(strQuery, function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
   }
   data=result.response;
   console.log('Response:', result.response);
});
 


var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  
  res.write(data);
}).listen(8000);
```

**OUTPUT:**

_

```
http_outgoing.js:653
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:653:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:621:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\docker\solr\solrnode.js:33:7)
    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:790:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the format of the http output, @see [`http.response.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback).
If you want for example to return the response as JSON, you need to :

- add a parameter to the Solr request (if the output format is not JSON by default)
- set the http response header accordingly
- stringify the json output
- call [`response.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)

```js
const strQuery = client.query()
  .q('type2:veg')
  .addParams({
    wt: 'json',
    indent: true
  })
;

// ... search & set data variable

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
});
server.listen(8000);
```